# How to list dates in sequence between two points of time in django templates?

Tags: django

I want to autogenerate a timetable. I created a model as follows:

```
class Timetable(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    fromDate = models.DateField(blank = False, null = False)
    toDate = models.DateField(blank = False, null = False)
    heading = models.CharField(max_length =50,blank=True, null = True)
```

I want to make a list of dates between fromDate and toDate and display that list on a template.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible, we can convert the two dates to their *ordinal* (the number of days since January 1, 1) and then use `range(..)` and map these back to a date, like:

```
from datetime import date

def date_range(from_date, to_date):
    return map(date.fromordinal, range(from_date.toordinal(), to_date.toordinal()+1))
```

for example, we can call this with:

```
>>> list(date_range(date(2019, 2, 3), date(2019, 2, 9)))
[datetime.date(2019, 2, 3), datetime.date(2019, 2, 4), datetime.date(2019, 2, 5), datetime.date(2019, 2, 6), datetime.date(2019, 2, 7), datetime.date(2019, 2, 8), datetime.date(2019, 2, 9)]
```

we can use that, for example in a view, and thus pass it like:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render

def some_view(request, pk):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Timetable, pk=pk)
    context = {
        'obj': obj,
        'date_range': date_range(obj.fromDate, obj.toDate)
    }
    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

and render it in the template, for example with:

```
{% for curdate in date_range %}
    {{ curdate }}
{% endrange %}
```

Comment: this works if i have only one timetable, what if Timetable is a query set?

Comment: @AddepalliSuryaveda: you can simply add a method to your `Timetable` model to obtain the timerange per `Timetable`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# in models.py

class Timetable(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    fromDate = models.DateField(blank = False, null = False)
    toDate = models.DateField(blank = False, null = False)
    heading = models.CharField(max_length =50,blank=True, null = True)
    def date_range(self):
        return list(map(date.fromordinal, range(self.fromDate.toordinal(),              self.toDate.toordinal()+1)))

# in views.py

def fun(request):
    template_name = 'x'
    timetables = Timetable.objects.filter(user = request.user)
    context = {'timetables':timetables}
    return render(request, template_name, context)

# in template

{% for table in timetables %}
<div class="table">
  {% for i in table.date_range %}
  <li>{{ i.month }}/ {{ i.day }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```